# Bulk programming with unique id

Tags: production

When programming hundreds of thousands (or more) MCUs or EEPROMs, it seems that companies need to add unique serial numbers to each programmed unit -- don't want two units with the same serial number.

How is this done in practice, especially for MCUs with internal FLASH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy devices that have unique serial numbers in them and connect your MCU to them. Serial EEPROMs that have this feature are available from [Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/SiteComm_sg/documents/DeviceDoc/en542943.pdf)  and [Amtel](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT24MAC402.aspx).

For pure MCU solutions you would likely have programming software that programs the base image, then a station or step that programs the serial number as provided by an external PC, for example. The PC has software to make sure it increments each time.

Comment: Cool, didn't know EEPROMs now had this feature. Do any MCUs that you're aware of include a software accessible unique identifier?

Comment: That is how we do it. It isn't a uC feature. There is a byte in the EEPROM reserved for the serial number. The software guys developed a tech tool that is used for calibration and writing the serial number to EEPROM. It's all done over USB for the products it effects.

Answer (score 2):

Modern microcontrollers tend to provide unique serial numbers "out of the box". For example, STM32 family MCUs have a 96-bit Unique Device ID register. You'll need to use a simple hashing function to derive a shorter ID because serial numbers for ICs from the same batch only tend to differ in one or two bytes. See e.g. [here](http://false.ekta.is/2012/06/stm32-device-electronic-signature-unique-device-id-register/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since your main question is
*"How is this done in practice, especially for MCUs with internal FLASH?"*
i will summarize some possible solutions (depending on the device)

- the MCU already provides a factory side UID
- writing the UID to the internal EEPROM as part of production/calibration
- writing the UID to some kind of dedicated user signature section during production/calibration
- hard code the UID using an auto generated header file and recompile the source before flashing
- use an external device that provides a UID and access it during runtime

Answer (score 0):

The internal flash of the AVR MCUs is programmable, just like the program memory area. A typical chip programming appliance or set-up will have a feature that increments a serial number to be programmed once per programmed device. You can do it with the avrdude program for programming AVR chips, for example.

Comment: The AVR XMEGA series provides a read only 11-byte UID composed of lot number, wafer number and wafer coordinates.